# Removing blocks of text from a file

Tags: sed, grep, graphql

I have a graph QL schema file that has comments between triple speech marks;

```
"""
some text
"""
```

I need to remove the blocks and was wondering if anyone knows how to do this with regular expressions as I can then use sed or grep to remove the blocks

I don't own the API so cannot change the output.

Comment: You could use the GraphQL parser from GraphQL.js and then use a visitor to remove the comment nodes. And then use the printer to print the schema again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps sed:

```sh
sed '/"""/,/"""/d' <<END
a
"""
comment 1
"""
b
"""
comment 2
"""
c
END
```

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: this works except for the case when I have an empty line  in between the speech marks and the comment text

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)